# How to generate random vectors and store as multiple objects in R?

Tags: r, random

I want to generate multiple random vectors:

```
a <- rnorm(10)
b <- rnorm(10)
c <- rnorm(10)
```

Is there a way to do this more concisely? For example, doing the following assigns the same numbers to `a, b, c`, which is something I don't want.

```
a <- b <- c <- rnorm(10)
```

Another way is to use a for loop, but is there a more concise way?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

We can use `zeallot` multiple assignment operator (`%<-%` for this

```
library(zeallot)
c(a, b, c) %<-% replicate(3, rnorm(10), simplify = FALSE)
```

-checking

```
> head(a)
[1]  0.3268303 -0.3641770 -0.5644841 -1.9312762  0.1363512  1.5742827
> head(b)
[1] -0.2849812 -1.5234004  0.4008743 -0.4625301  0.9541247  0.6801852
> head(c)
[1] -0.8387253  2.1883784 -0.1846793 -0.8896609 -0.3637861 -1.1172537
```

---

It may be better to create a `list` and name it instead of creating multiple objects in the global environment i.e.

```
lst1 <- setNames(replicate(3, rnorm(10), simplify = FALSE), letters[1:3])
```